# MVC ValidationMessage for dynamic amount of decimal places

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a requirement to enforce a dynamic number of decimal places on a textbook input. I've seen examples on stack overflow of using property attributes and regex to enforce a set number of decimal places.

My requirement is dynamic. @Html.TextBoxFor() are generated dynamically and each one is linked to a property that has it's own decimal places requirements. So if a result requires 3 decimal places, even if the result is 1 it must be entered as 1.000. However the next result may have 5 decimal places required so that would need to be 1.00000.

Property is

```
List<Result> results
```

Where Result is

```
public class Result{

public float NumericResult;

public int DecimalPlaceRequired;

}
```

What's the best way to implement this dynamic validation in MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to write customer validation attribute inherit from `ValidationAttribute` and `override` method.

```
override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
```

Getting `DecimalPlaceRequired` value from `validationContext.ObjectInstance` instance. then valid by `Regex`.

```
public class CutomerAuthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as Result;
        if (model != null)
        {
            string pattern = GetPattern(model);

            if (Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), pattern))
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Please input correct float number");
    }

    private string GetPattern(Result model)
    {
        string pattern = "^[+]?[0-9]+";

        if (model.DecimalPlaceRequired > 0)
            pattern += "[.][0-9]{" + model.DecimalPlaceRequired + "}";

        pattern += "$";

        return pattern;
    }
}
```

Add `CutomerAuth` attribute on `NumericResult` property.

```
public class Result
{
    [CutomerAuth]
    public float NumericResult { get; set; }

    public int DecimalPlaceRequired { get; set; }

}
```

Here is a sample for you

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nbOTNx)

Comment: Thanks d-Shih, this works. Is there something extra I need to do to get it to validate client side ? The built in validation methods validate client side correctly but when using this custom one the form still submits to server even though I debug and can see it fails validation when the wrong decimal places are used.

Comment: Never mind, serverside validation is sufficient. Thanks mate.